# Word between "proficient" and "mastery"?

Tags: synonyms

I'm writing a résumé for the first time and I want to convey that I have a near-mastery of a programming language. Most sample resumes use "proficient", but that sounds like I'm not very good with the programming language. I have almost 10 years of extensive experience with the language, so I feel qualified to claim that I have "mastery" of the language. However, I don't want to use "mastery" because that sounds arrogant.

What's a word with a meaning between "proficient" and "mastery"?

Comment: Re-check *proficient* in another dictionary to whatever led you to believe it makes you sound like you aren't good with something.

Comment: I just checked and it can be synonymous with "competent."

Answer (score 0):

"Proficiency" is an synonym of "mastery". Another is "command". These mean that you have a high level of skill in an area. According to you self-assessment you can say, "good command", "highly developed skills in.." etc. You might like to re-style your piece to read, for example, "high level of expertise" or "completely competent and well-experienced...".  For thinking about degrees of ability, are you expert, advanced, or competent?